# Implementing pyglet breaks my once working framebuffer OpenGL code

Tags: python, opengl, framebuffer, pyglet, pyopengl

This question repeats my earlier one but my earlier one was a failure because I didn't copy some vital information correctly, so I have to redo it.

I'm getting an error with a call to an OpenGL function. Maybe pyglet isn't initialising OpenGL correctly? The error happens with a simple function that worked before:

```
 def setup_framebuffer(surface):
   #Create texture if not done already
   if surface.texture is None:
      create_texture(surface)
   #Render child to parent
   if surface.frame_buffer is None:
      surface.frame_buffer =  glGenFramebuffersEXT(1)
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, surface.frame_buffer)
   glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface.texture, 0)
   glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT)
   glViewport(0,0,surface._scale[0],surface._scale[1])
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
   glLoadIdentity() #Load the projection matrix
   gluOrtho2D(0,surface._scale[0],0,surface._scale[1])
```

The error is:

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, surface.frame_buffer)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: : wrong type

Wrong type? Then is glGenFramebuffersEXT(1) giving the wrong type now? Why would that be?

Before that function is called I initialise a class instance which manages my game. Here's the **init** method:

```
pyglet.options['audio'] = ('alsa','openal','directsound','silent')
  self.keys = [False] * 323
  self.events = []
  self.title = title
  self.game_size = game_size
  self.first_screen = (1280,720) #Take 120 pixels from the height because the menu bar, window bar and dock takes space
  config = pyglet.gl.Config(alpha_size=8,double_buffer=True,sample_buffers=1,samples=4)
  self.window = pyglet.window.Window(game_size[0],game_size[1],title,True,config=config)
  self.window.set_handler('on_draw',self.game_loop)
  self.window.set_handler('on_resize',self.reshaped)
  self.window.set_handler('on_key_press',self.keydown)
  self.window.set_handler('on_key_release',self.keyup)
  self.window.set_handler('on_mouse_press',self.mouse_func)
  glViewport(0,0,self.first_screen[0],self.first_screen[1]) #Creates the viewport which is mapped to the window
  glEnable(GL_BLEND) #Enable alpha blending
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) #Enable 2D Textures
  glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE) #Enable Multisampling anti-aliasing
  glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH) #Enable antialiased polygons
  glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
  glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST)
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
  glLoadIdentity() #Load the projection matrix
  gluOrtho2D(0,1280,720,0) #Set an orthorgraphic view
  self.game_gap = (0,0)
  self.on_exit = on_exit
  self.mod_key = 1024 if sys.platform == "darwin" else 64
  Surface.__init__(self,game_size)
  self.screen_change = True
  self.frames = [time.time()]
  self.fps = 60
  self.last_time = 0
  self.fade_surface = Surface([1280,720])
  pyglet.font.add_file(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + "/NEUROPOL.ttf")
  pyglet.font.load('NEUROPOL')
```

Surface is a class that I made which acts a bit like the pygame.Surface class but uses OpenGL textures.

That method sets up the Window and OpenGL (Probably not properly which is the problem?) and after calling it I set-up some things for my game which uses the setup_framebuffer function for rendering to textures. Then pyglet.app.run() is called which should hopefully run my game_loop method since I did self.window.set_handler('on_draw,self.game_loop) but my game crashes before it gets there.

This is the first time I've use pyglet. The documentation doesn't explain to me what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just edit your previous question?

Comment: Would anyone look at it since it's now a day old? I can't really risk this sorry because I'm using this for my A2 Computing project and pyglet seems to be the only way to solve a few remaining issues. I only have 4 weeks to do this and I need to do some write-up with testing as well.

Comment: You should update or delete your previous question so that people don't waste their time on it.

Comment: If you can get one more person to downvote this question (since it is a deliberate dupe by the same author), then the author deletes the question, he will receive a 'peer pressure' badge! Let's make it happen! Fire those downvotes, people, you're doing him a favour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glBindFramebufferEXT expects pointer to a buffer. AFAIK, you have to use [ctypes](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/using_opengl.html) in this case.

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from ctypes import c_uint, byref

fb = c_uint()
glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, byref(fb))
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fb)
```

Search [pyglet mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/pyglet-users) for better examples. And BTW:

```
>> glGenFramebuffersEXT(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: this function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**Edit:**
I should have guessed that you are using pyOpenGL:

```
fb = int(glGenFramebuffersEXT(1))
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fb)
```

Comment: I have been using from OpenGL.GL.EXT.framebuffer_object import * and other imports from pyOpenGL.

I take from this that from pyglet.gl import * gives the same functions with slight differences that should work. So pyglet comes with it's own OpenGL wrapper which is different from pyOpenGL?

"surface.texture = glGenTextures(1)
TypeError: this function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
"

Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems like I have more to change. It also seems pyglet's OpenGL interface is closer to other languages than pyOpenGL. In some ways that is better but mostly it's annoying because pyOpenGL made more sense. No need to import cTypes for a start.

Comment: Yep, pyglet has it's own wrapper. Quote from pyglet docs: The interface is provided by the pyglet.gl package. To use it you will need a good knowledge of OpenGL, C and ctypes. You may prefer to use OpenGL without using ctypes, in which case you should investigate PyOpenGL. PyOpenGL provides similar functionality with a more "Pythonic" interface, and will work with pyglet without any modification.

Comment: "PyOpenGL provides similar functionality with a more "Pythonic" interface, and will work with pyglet without any modification"

Well, pyOpenGL didn't work with pyglet when I tried it so I'm just going to have to use the pyglet version which isn't giving any issues at the moment.

Comment: PyOpenGL and pyglet work perfectly with each other, by which I mean that PyOpenGL will happily use the OpenGL context provided by opening a pyglet window, and you can interleave OpenGL calls which use pyglet with those which use PyOpenGL. However, one is not a drop-in replacement for the other because, as you have noticed, PyOpenGL provides a more convenient API.